# How sql and Hql Query Cache Works in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Please anyone explain me how hql and sql query cache works in hibernate. I'hv googled alot but don't find a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: [Something](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-hibernate-second-level-cache-works.html) useful, might help you.

Comment: Hey! ankur cool blog, but i know how second level cache and session local cache works.i jus want to know if my hql contains multiple tables or joins in fact then how caching works.Also is this caching also works if i fire native SQL?

Comment: Did you had look at [this](http://i-proving.com/2006/08/29/sql-vs-hql-with-the-session-cache/) one.

Comment: yes i had,m sorry to say but my aim is to know if the caching also works if i fire native sql using hibernate but as much your blog tell me caching will not works in the case of native sql.

Comment: This is what i interprete from your blog.